# Play movie in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to play a Youtube video in Excel on the click of a menu command, however I cannot find the parameter to pass the URL to. Does anyone know it? I know filename is an option, but I would need to be able to pass the movie parameter in the properties. Also, would anyone know how to autoplay and auto delete the sheet once the movie is over?

```
Option Explicit
Sub movie()
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Instructions"
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.11", _
    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=99.75, Top:=38.25, Width:= _
    953.25, Height:=461.25).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about playing the movie, but you can place some code at the end of the Sub to close the active worksheet through the use of the line

```
ActiveSheet.Delete
```

Hope this helps,

lewisthegruffalo

Comment: Well the problem is there seems to be connection between the player and the actual sheet, so activesheet.delete would not work. Thanks anyway!